# Show options while typing in search box

Tags: ruby, search, sinatra

I have a table for providers (services) and I'd like to be able to type, say 'ac' and options like acupuncture should show up in a drop down. I'm not sure what exactly this is called.

This has always managed to confuse me. How do i go about this with Sinatra? I don't expect a full code, just a path that i can follow.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.